# python: multiple .dat's in multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to sort some data into (np.)arrays and get stuck with a problem.

I have 1000 .dat files and I need to put the data from them in 1000 different arrays. Further, every array should contain data depend on coordinates [i] [j] [k] (this part I've done already and the code looks like this (this is kind of "short" version):

```
with open('177500.dat', newline='') as csvfile:
    f = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in f:
        <some code which works pretty good>
    cV = [[[[] for k in range(kMax)] for j in range(jMax)] for i in range(iMax)] 

with open('177500.dat', newline='') as csvfile:
    f = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    <some code which works also good>
            values = np.array([np.float64(row[i]) for i in range(3, rowLen)])
            cV[int(row[0])][int(row[1])][int(row[2])] = values
```

After this, i can print cV [i] [j] [k] and I get all data which is contained in one .dat file at the coordinates [i] [j] [k].

And now I need to create cV [i] [j] [k] **[n]** to get the data from the specific file number **n** at the coordinates [i] [j] [k]. And I absolutely don't know how can I tell python to put the data into the "right" place.

I tried some things like this:

```
for m in range(160000,182501,2500):
with open ('output/%d.dat' % m, newline='') as csvfile:
  <bla bla code>
cV = [[[[[] for k in range(kMax)] for j in range(jMax)] for i in range(iMax)] for n in range(tMax)] 

if len(row) == rowLen:
            values = [np.array([np.float64(row[i]) for i in range (3, rowLen)]) for n in range(tMax)]
            for n in range(tMax):
                cV[int(row[0])][int(row[1])][int(row[2])][int(n)] = values[n]
```

But this surely didn't work because python don't know what the hack should be this **[n]** after the values.

So, how can I tell pyhton to put this [i] [j] [k] data from the file nr. **n** in the array cV [i] [j] [k] **[n]**?

Thanks in advance

C.

P.S. I didn't post the whole code because I don't think it is necessary. All arrays are created properly, but the thing which isn't working ist the data in them.

Comment: This data structure looks horrendous to work with. Is there an absolute requirement for it to be like this?

Comment: Kind of. How would you handle it?

Comment: Well, I couldn't be sure without knowing your objective, but I would probably build a dictionary with tuples as keys e.g. `{(i, j, k, n): corresponding_file_data}`. From what I can gather, you just want to be able to use indices as a filtering mechanism to locate individual files and this would be a lot easier than nesting lists to this kind of level.

Comment: Later I need to calculate some things with this [i][j][k] data. The data contains physical pressure/velocity/density of a fluid from a CFD simulation at some coordinates (x,y,z), and I'm not sure whether it is possible with dictionaries. E.g. I calculate mean values at cell centers and use for it functions like mean = ([i][j][k]+[i+1][j][k])/2 and so on

Comment: A dictionary itself is unordered, but since you're using tuples as keys, you could still access the data in the same way e.g. `mean = (my_dict.get((i, j, k)) + my_dict.get((i+1, j, k))/2`. You can still store data as lists against those keys too. A while since learned about CFD; what does each `.dat` represent? A single cube in a 3D space, or a complete  setup with a list of pressure/velocity/density stored against x, y, z coords?

Comment: Ok, seems like I should try it with dict's. .dat files represents results of a simulation on mesh nodes. By results I mean pressure, velocity, density and also the xyz coordinates.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand your code to see if I can suggest an answer. Can you please post a bit of something about what's in the dat files?

Comment: These results look just like a table with numbers.

Comment: Sure
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x1zarfzosn77w32/Pulse3D_tret17.7500.dat?dl=0 

This is one of the files.

Comment: Aha, great. So within a single simulation, you want to be able to access physical properties of any node by its x, y, z coords. And then do you want to be able to do cross-comparisons for a specific node across multiple simulations?

Comment: Accross multiple timesteps (n), yes. To approximate the time derivatives.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you mean, last clarification. So the `.dat` file records the values at every single node on every timestep. i.e. within a single '.dat' file, the same `(x, y, z)` coords will appear multiple times but with different physical properties stored against them? And each time they reappear, it's a new, consecutive, timestep? If this is correct, it will take some time for me to mull over exactly the best way and provide an answer (since dict keys must be unique).

Comment: Well, the .dat file contains two instances of (50, 50, 50) coords. So I need something concrete on what represents a "timestep". Is it one simulation now with 2000 iterations, with data split across 1000 files?

Comment: Hello again and thanks for your suggestion. Actualy every `.dat` file contains only one timestep. The reason why the some points appears twice is because it is a data of a cube, the points are divided into groups of surfaces and some vertices belongs to more than one surface.

Answer (score 0):

I think building arrays like this is going to make things more complicated for you. It would be easier to build a dictionary using tuples as keys. In the example file you sent me, each `(x, y, z)` pair was repeated twice, making me think that each file contains data on *two* iterations of a total solution of 2000 iterations. Dictionaries must have unique keys, so for each file I have implemented another counter, `timestep`, that can increment when collating data from a single file.

Now, if I wanted coords (1, 2, 3) on the 3rd timestep, I could do `simulation[(1, 2, 3, 3)]`.

```
import csv
import numpy as np

'''
Made the assumptions that:
    -Each file contains two iterations from a simulation of 2000 iterations
    -Each file is numbered sequentially. Each time the same (x, y, z) coords are 
    discovered, it represents the next timestep in simulation

Accessing data is via a tuple key (x, y, z, n) with n being timestep
'''

simulation = {}
file_count = 1
timestep = 1
num_files = 2

for x in range(1, num_files + 1):
    with open('sim_file_{}.dat'.format(file_count), 'r') as infile:
        second_read = False
        reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ')
        for row in reader:
            item = [float(x) for x in row]
            if row:
                if (not second_read and not
                    any(simulation.get((item[0], item[1], item[2], timestep), []))):
                    timestep += 1
                    second_read = True
                simulation[(item[0], item[1], item[2], timestep)] = np.array(item[3:])

    file_count += 1
    timestep += 1
    second_read = False
```

Comment: This works pretty good, but I'm afraid, I should use arrays further. I don't need only to access data in the `.dat` files but also to calculate lots of things with it; and for these things arrays are sort of better even if they are more "horrible" compared to dicts.

I'll try to do something similar with my code to access the different timesteps. If it won't work I ask you again ;)